# Directive not working for non numeric values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-decorator

I have directive to forbid entering non-numeric symbols in input

Here is directive

```
  import { NgControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { HostListener, Directive } from "@angular/core";

    @Directive({
      exportAs: "number-directive",
      selector: "number-directive, [number-directive]",
    })
    export class NumberDirective {
      private el: NgControl;
      constructor(ngControl: NgControl) {
        this.el = ngControl;
      }
      // Listen for the input event to also handle copy and paste.
      @HostListener("input", ["$event.target.value"])
      onInput(value: string): void {
        // Use NgControl patchValue to prevent the issue on validation
        this.el.control.patchValue(value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").slice(0));
      }
    }
```

Here is how I use it on `input`

```
  <input
  type="text"
  tabindex="0"
  class="search__input form-control-md + {{class}}"
  [value]="config.value"
  [required]="config.required"
  [attr.maxlength]="config.maxLength"
  [attr.minLength]="config.minLength"
  #inputElem
  number-directive
/>
```

But I still can write `aaaaa` or any words

Where can be my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Suspect two root causes:

1. **Forgot to add `NumberDirective` to `declarations` for *app.module.ts***.

   You need to add `NumberDirective` to `declarations` for *app.module.ts* to register the directive.

```js
@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [..., NumberDirective],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

2. **No provider for`NgControl` for your `<input>` element.**

   You will get the error message as below as missing `[(ngModel)]` for the input element. The directive expects that it is a `NgControl`. Hence it needs to have `[(ngModel)]`.

   Or you need `[formControl]="configControl"` for your `<input>` element.

> Error: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[NgControl -> NgControl -> NgControl]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for NgControl!

```
<input
  type="text"
  tabindex="0"
  class="search__input form-control-md + {{ class }}"
  [value]="config.value"
  [required]="config.required"
  [attr.maxlength]="config.maxLength"
  [attr.minLength]="config.minLength"
  #inputElem
  number-directive
  [(ngModel)]="config.value"
/>
```

OR

```
<input
  type="text"
  tabindex="0"
  class="search__input form-control-md + {{ class }}"
  [value]="config.value"
  [required]="config.required"
  [attr.maxlength]="config.maxLength"
  [attr.minLength]="config.minLength"
  #inputElem
  number-directive
  [formControl]="configControl"
/>
```

```js
configControl = new FormControl();
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bh1njn)

Comment: I not using ngModel, I using forms and formControls. Maybe here is problem?

Comment: Yes, bingo, you need `[formControl]='configControl'`.